# Obtain evenly spaced unit vectors from the positive orthant of a N dimensional euclidean space.

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

So I'm writing a program to generate M unit vectors (M is not guaranteed to be very large) of an N dimensional euclidean space. I want these M vectors to be as evenly spaced as possible.

For 2 dimensions, this is simple, just compute c = 90/M and generate M increments of (cos(c), sin(c)). But I'm not sure how to do this for an arbitrary dimensions N. Any advise is appreciated.

Comment: "I want these M vectors to be as evenly spaced as possible." You should make this formulation more certain. Without concretization this problem cannot be solved even for $N=3$, except special cases like $M=2$ or $M=2N$.